# Problem positioning div in page with css

Tags: css, margin

I'm having a problem trying to position a div in my web page, here's my test site:
http://dirtymind.jvsoftware.com/

The problem is with the left side bar (the one with the login inputs and stuff), it's currently a div which I used negative top and left margins to position it where it is, but depending on the screen resolution it moves to the left or right. Obviously this is beacuse I'm using margins this is how css would work but I don't know how to get this same results otherwise.

Does anyone know how to position my sidebar on place regarding the resolution?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: for me it's not the effective method to use float left in this case. use position absolute instead for the left navigation.

Comment: I tried using absolute and relative positioning as well, but I got the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah what he said:

```
<div id='wrapper' style='width:800px'>
  <div id='left-sidebar' style='width:200px;float:left'>
     ...content...
  </div>

  <div id='contenedor' style='width:600px;float:left'>
     ...content...
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I tought about this as well, but how could I center the content then? See that the div that's centered is the "contenedor" div, if I center the wrapper the page would look some pixels moved to the right.

Comment: Center the content with another empty div on the other side of it, same width as the sidebar:

Comment: like this <wrapper 1000><left-sidebar 200><contenedor 600><right-sidebar 200>

Answer (score 0):

Well you already have a wrapper in place.... Why not give it a hard width of the main content area+the width of the side bar and any spacing you want between the two. then you can just float both of them to the left. Or you could set the wrappr to position relative (not assigning a position) and then use position absolute on the side bar and punh in the coordinates from 0 point of the wrapper.

Comment: I tought about this as well, but how could I center the content then? See that the div that's centered is the "contenedor" div, if I center the wrapper the page would look some pixels moved to the right.

Comment: ummm `#wrapper {margin: 0 auto;}` should center it... unless im missing something...